# Ввод переменных в файл построчно

Tags: pascal

Нужно записать переменную n в одной строке, а переменную m в другой строке.
Код, конечно, написала, простой, и ошибки не вижу.
Но компилятор выдает в строке:

```
append(gr_vhod);
```

сообщение о том, что задан неверный тип.
Что нужно изменить?

```
program z_5;

uses crt;

type gr = file of integer;

var n : integer;
    m : integer;
    gr_vhod : gr;

BEGIN
   assign(gr_vhod,'vhod.txt');
   rewrite(gr_vhod);

   writeln('Vvedite N: ');
   readln(n);

   write(gr_vhod,n);

   close(gr_vhod);

   writeln('Vvedite M: ');
   readln(m);

   append(gr_vhod);
   write(gr_vhod,m);

END.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем закрывать файл перед тем как выводить второе число? И еще, если вы хотите после выполнения программы открыть полученный файл и там что-либо прочитать, используйте текстовый формат. file of integer сохраняет файлы в бинарном виде, его вообще в обычном текстовом редакторе не прочитаешь, переносы строк для него не применимы.

Попробуйте так:

```
program z_5;

uses crt;

var n : integer;
    m : integer;
    gr_vhod : Text;

BEGIN
   assign(gr_vhod,'vhod.txt');
   rewrite(gr_vhod);

   writeln('Vvedite N: ');
   readln(n);

   writeln(gr_vhod,n); {чтобы каждый раз выводить с новой строки используйте writeln}

   writeln('Vvedite M: ');
   readln(m);

   writeln(gr_vhod,m);
   close(gr_vhod);
END.
```

Comment: Ну свой ответ я обновил.

Comment: Спасибо, @Shrek, Вы мне очень помогли.

Comment: Ахах,@elenavictory интересно, а ответ принят не мой, ну ладно я поплачу и смирюсь.

Answer (score 1):

Включаем внимательность.

```
BEGIN
   assign(gr_vhod,'vhod.txt');
   rewrite(gr_vhod);

   writeln('Vvedite N: ');
   readln(n);

   write(gr_vhod,n);

   close(gr_vhod);

   writeln('Vvedite M: ');
   readln(m);

   append(gr_vhod); // append должна идти после чего? правильно после Assign() которого нет после close(); правильно?
   write(gr_vhod,m);
 // закрываем файл
END.
```

Принимаем ответ и внимательно кодим в следующий раз.

ps в файле будет только последняя переменная!

Да вам не только внимательность еще и логику включить! и правильно написать вопрос!

Во первых файл тогда не должен быть

```
type gr = file of integer;
```

просто

```
   type gr = file;

   type gr = file of string;
```

А дальше один раз открыть его 2 раза записать и закрыть.
писать за вас никто не будет. больше для решения вашей задачи расписывать нечего.
Нужно включить логику, воображение, и стремление к изучению косяков.

**PS кстати строку**

```
program blah-blah;
```

Можно не писать, когда научитесь правильно и быстро писать на паскале, то каждая лишняя строчка в коде будет писаться "влом" эта строка нужна для названия программы, оно вообще нигде не используется, проще писать комментарии о чем программа, но уже наверное, после её написания.

а так написать можно еще покороче.

```
uses crt;
type gr=file of string;
var   n,i : integer;
  gr_vhod : gr;
BEGIN
   assign(gr_vhod,'vhod.dat');
   rewrite(gr_vhod);
      for i:=1 to 2 do
       Begin
        write('Vvedite '+i+' chislo: '); // синтаксис не помню
        readln(n);
        writeln(gr_vhod,n);
       End;   
    close(gr_vhod);
    ReadLn;
END.
```

Чем я и любил паскаль, так тем что всегда можно сократить код, после того как его криво напишешь. особенно функции и процедуры которые выносишь отдельно в свой модель, тогда программа вообще в количестве кода сокращается в разы!

Comment: Результат один и тот же....



assign(gr_vhod,'vhod.txt');
   append(gr_vhod);

   writeln('Vvedite M: ');
   readln(m);

   write(gr_vhod,m);

Comment: я понимаю, что тогда в файле будет только последняя переменная. Потому что используется rewrite(); Но мне нужно записать обе переменные.

Comment: Да не потому что используется rewrite? а потому что тип у файла integer а в него можно записать как я помню одно число только.

Comment: @Shrek, вообще-то я не просила за меня что-то писать.

По поводу rewrite(); преподаватель ясно сказал, что rewrite(); создает новый файл и обнуляет уже существующий файл из рабочего каталога, и запись, естественно, теряется.

Comment: @elenavictory,

1. Не нужно закрывать файл перед вводом второй переменной. Просто записываете два числа (или сколько нужно будет), а потом уже закрываете.
2. Если указан тип переменной файла file of integer, то в нем не будет переносов строк (а также чисел в понятном для человека виде). Если нужны переносы строк и понятный текст, используйте тип text.
3. Как уже было сказано, append можно использовать только если тип gr = text.
4. Если используете тип text, и нужно чтобы каждое число было с новой строки, выводите их через writeln

Comment: >rewrite(); преподаватель ясно сказал, что rewrite(); создает новый >файл и обнуляет уже существующий файл из рабочего каталога, 

Преподаватель у вас просто моск! только не из рабочего каталога я бы уточнял на его месте такие вот моменты.
<pre>
<code>
assign(); //делает ссылку на файл
rewrite(); // открывает файл на запись и удаляет внутренности если файл есть, если файла нет то он его типа создает.
</code>
</pre>
я это к тому что
> файл из рабочего каталога
фраза твоего препода не актуальна вообще, либо он не хочет вам рассказывать либо не дает нужного материала.

Comment: Это был преподаватель, который сделал видеокурс по изучению pascal. Как он сказал, так и запомнила:) А вот спросить подробности уже никак.

Comment: Кстати, program bla-bla в моем случае писать все же надо. Когда в отчете прикладываю листинг программ, то сразу видно, где одна программа закончилась, где началась другая.

Comment: @elenavictory, пишите конечно, не нужно гнаться за меньшим количеством строк, лучше пусть код будет понятным, тем более что одна строка погоды не делает.

Answer (score 1):

Дело всё в том, что функция Append работает только с текстовыми файлами, а с типизированными и нетипизированными файлами она не работает. И ещё: мне не понятно зачем после внесения одной записи закрывать файл, а потом его опять открывать? Открыли файл - работаем с ним - закончили работу с файлом - закрываем его. Код поправил, вроде работает. Для числовых файлов лучше ставить расширение .dat.

```
program z_5;

uses crt;

type gr = file of integer;

var n : integer;
    m : integer;
    gr_vhod : gr;

BEGIN
   assign(gr_vhod,'vhod.dat');
   rewrite(gr_vhod);

   write('Vvedite N: ');
   readln(n);

   write(gr_vhod,n);

   write('Vvedite M: ');
   readln(m);

   write(gr_vhod,m);

   close(gr_vhod);

   WriteLn('Davi na ENTER!!!');
   ReadLn;
END.
```

Но после работы программы Вы не увидите в файле ни одного числа, если хотите увидеть число, то нужно работать с текстовым файлом.

Comment: > WriteLn('Davi na knopku ANY KEY!!!');
>   Repeat Until (KeyPressed);

это прошу прощения пи***ц вы понимаете что при таком вот условии вы просто делаете глупость!

readLn; все больше ничего не нужно, нафига цикл?

Comment: Это не глупость - я так всегда делал! Программа просто будет ждать нажатия клавиши. В Delphi мне приходится писать ReadLn (из-за отсутствия модуля CRT), а в Паскале или Lazarus-е так. Мне так удобно.

Comment: Ты понимаешь что такое цикл и простое ожидание нажатия кнопки.

Что 
>Repeat Until (KeyPressed);

ни разу не одно и тоже что

>readLn;

Зачем запускать бесконечный цикл, когда ты просто ждешь нажатия кнопки? Этим ты пишешь говнокод, а люди потом пишут подобные вещи и не понимают почему у них программа в 300 килобайт памяти жрет на 300 метров.

Comment: В книгах и примерах, по которым я учился, не было ничего про это сказано. Всегда пользовался этим, и не задумывался об оптимизации. Если это правда, то, спасибо, что открыл мне глаза.

Comment: Кстати да, это правда - загрузка процессора вырастает при этом и прога жрёт 200 метров. Спасибо тебе, @Shrek, за такую полезную информацию. Этого я не знал.

Comment: Ну это же логически можно предположить ;)

Хотя про килобайты и метры я так на вскидку написал, оказалось в точку:)

ps я начинал с паскаля, потом делфи, теперь web языки. но иногда возвращаюсь к делфям+mysql+php вааще прикольное сочетание.

награждай меня очками уважухи :))) хахаха